# Removing a string from a string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can i remove from **data** to end of the string in a single function? I need to pass the string and get the desired output. How can i trim the string which is not needed ?
How can i achieve this?

```
   var firsturl = "www.google.com/sample/data/merge.html"
    var secondurl =  "www.google.com/sample/data/change.html"
```

expected output

```
var firsturl = "www.google.com/sample/"
var secondurl =  "www.google.com/sample/"
```

I have tried this much, but to the end, the word changes.

```
let url = window.location.href
 url.replace('data', '')
```

Comment: URL's origin and protocol will remain same for both variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String#replace` with a regular expression:

```js
var firsturl = "www.google.com/sample/data/merge.html"
var secondurl =  "www.google.com/sample/data/change.html"

function trimData(str) {
  return str.replace(/data.*$/, '');
}

console.log(trimData(firsturl));
console.log(trimData(secondurl));
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split()` on the string by `data` then take the string from first index:

```js
var firsturl = "www.google.com/sample/data/merge.html"
var secondurl =  "www.google.com/sample/data/change.html"

firsturl = firsturl.split('data')[0];
secondurl = secondurl.split('data')[0];
console.log(firsturl);
console.log(secondurl);
```

**Using Function:**

```js
function getSubString(str){
  return str.split('data')[0];
}
var firsturl = "www.google.com/sample/data/merge.html";
var secondurl =  "www.google.com/sample/data/change.html";
console.log(getSubString(firsturl));
console.log(getSubString(secondurl));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split by '/' and get the firts and second part by destructuring:

```js
var firstUrl = "www.google.com/sample/data/merge.html";

var [part1, part2] = firstUrl.split('/');
var res = [part1, part2].join('/');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be simply solved by using regex and str.replace() method provided by javascript itself

```
var firsturl = "www.google.com/sample/data/merge.html"
var secondurl =  "www.google.com/sample/data/change.html"
function trimmer(regex,str){
     return str.replace(new RegExp(regex,'i'),'');
    }
changedFirstUrl = trimmer('data.*',firstUrl);
changedSecondUrl = trimmer('data.*',secondUrl);
```

With this the result you get is `www.google.com/sample/`
I hope this helps you
Happy coding